# C# Linq and lambda

Tags: c#, linq

How does **Select(int.Parse)** work in such Linq expression?

```
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();                 //ok
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();         //ok
```

Why example with Console.Writeline returns compilation error?

```
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(Console.WriteLine).ToList();         //error
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(x => Console.WriteLine(x)).ToList(); //ok
```

When it is allowed to omit lambda like (x => ....(x))

Comment: the 4th line shouldn't compile aswell

Comment: The 3rd and 4th are attempting to produce a List. What do you think that list can be a list *of* ?

Comment: Informally, `Select<T, U>` expects as its argument a function that takes `T`s and produces `U`s. Normally this happens implicitly, for example, if you pass `int.Parse` the compiler will deduce that `T = string` and `U = int`. However, `T`and `U` have to be types, they cannot be `void`. `Console.WriteLine` returns `void` which is not a valid type, so lines 3 and 4 will not compile (both).

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ and the result is a `List<void>` ? :D

Comment: I deleted my comment, I was well off the mark there.

Answer (score 4):

`Console.WriteLine` as well as `int.Parse` are so-called *method groups*. Groups of methods. Because of the various overloads of those methods. It can be exactly one method, or multiple methods.

A method group can be converted to a delegate if the compiler can infer which method of the group is meant. For example the method group `int.Parse` can be a delegate to `int.Parse(string)` if a `Func<string, int>`is expected.

This works in your first example. `Select` expects a `Func<T, T2>` and your `T` is already set to be of type `string`. However, it does *not* work with your second example. Because while `Console.WriteLine` is a method group, not a single method in this group corresponds to the required `Func<T, T2>` because the return type of *all* of the methods in the group is `void`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `Select` looks somewhat like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
          this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
          Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

So for the `selector` a method (or lambda) with the signature

```
TResult Method(string s);
```

is expected. `Console.WriteLine()` is of return type `void` which is *not a valid type* for `TResult`. So in fact **both lines**:

```
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(Console.WriteLine).ToList();
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').Select(x => Console.WriteLine(x)).ToList();
```

**don't compile**. Are you sure you really compiled that second line? My compiler raises error [CS0411](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411) for both lines.

Answer (score 1):

Select is a projections statement, it transforms your object into a new object that you specify inside the `Select`.You need to loop and execute the WriteLine:

```
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x=> {  Console.WriteLine(x); });
```

Select expects a parameter `Func<char, T>`, `Console.WriteLine` doesn't match that.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all LINQ extensions accept a **function** that returns a value. `Console.WriteLine` does not return anything, so it can't be used as parameter.

```
"12345".Select(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); return x; }).ToList(); // this will work 

"12345".Select(int.TryParse).ToList(); // this will NOT work because TryParse needs more than one parameter


"12345".ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // this will work because .ForEach accepts a method that does not return anything (void) 

"12345".ToList().ForEach(int.Parse); // this will NOT work
```

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed when the method signature is the same as LinQ expects.

In your first case, the `Select`'s expected signature **a method with one `string` parameter and return value of `int`** (or simply `Func<string, int>`) and `int.Parse` method has **the same** signature, that's why it's working;

while in the second case, the `Console.WriteLine`'s signature is **a method with one `string` parameter and no return value (or return value of special type `void`)** (or simply `Action<string>`), and hence signature that `Select` expects and signature that `Console.WriteLine` has do not match.

Comment: It's `Func<string,int>` not `Func<int, string>` and btw: the second version won't compile neither, as `void` is _not_ a valid return type for a `Select` lambda.